# How do you pass arguments from one function to another?

Tags: python

Sorry for the newbie question guys, but I'm relatively new to python.  I want to write a function that passes keyword and value arguments into another function:

e.g.

```
def function_that_passes_arguments(arguments):
    some_other_function(arguments)
```

so when I call the first function they are passed into the second... e.g.

```
function_that_passes_arguments(arg1=1, arg2=2)
```

is effectively

```
some_other_function(arg1=1, arg2=2)
```

The argument names will change so it is important that I pass both keyword and value from one function to another.

Answer (score 7):

Accept `*args, **kwargs` and pass those to the called function:

```
def function_that_passes_arguments(*args, **kwargs):
    some_other_function(*args, **kwargs)
```

In both places you can also use regular arguments - the only requirement is that the `*` and `**` arguments are the last ones.

Comment: In the given example, `function_that_passes_arguments = some_other function` would work just as well.

Comment: Yeah, but that's most likely not what @brett wants. Chances are good that there will be some code before/after the call.